How to type corner brackets on a Chromebook?
How do I type

"「" U+300C LEFT CORNER BRACKET
"」" U+300D RIGHT CORNER BRACKET

on a Chromebook?
Or is the only way via typing raw codes?

This is better asked on Super User SE (https://superuser.com/). You should also mention what IME you're using, because multiple IMEs for several languages can type those symbols.

All I know is that I am using https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/11383012 Chinese (Traditional) Pinyin.

For my OS(MS-Win11 Traditional Chinese), it’s just a matter of pressing 『Alt-Ctrl-，』  .
OS will popup:
https://ibb.co/fFLT4NW

